# Are there elections where the result tally is made public before the election is complete?

Tags: election, voting

The usual way of conducting elections is to start counting votes after the polls are closed or at least to only start announcing results after the last voter has cast their vote. There’s always some minor deviations (i.e. in the US preliminary results from the East Coast are available before Hawaii casts their last ballot) but overall elections attempt to keep the intermediary outcome secret until the end.

Are there systems where this isn’t the case and the voting tally is constantly updated in real time?

Comment: Every voter should be free by external influences. If earlier reporting is allowed it would be impossible to validate, officials could esily choose to take into account only certain votes or report votes only in certain areas in order to create a false impression of the partial status thus pushing voter to cast a strategic vote that suits them. Holding those officials accountable would not be possible. Such system is too prone to rigging.

Comment: I assume by "real time" you mean during the time that voting is still in progress, yes? (I might point out that the FINAL results of  Dixville Notch NH is announced by the election official BEFORE the polls open in Manchester NH. )

Comment: @BobE correct so they count the votes in real time and keep updating the dashboard

Comment: Is the "vote tally" you reference available to the general public?  (In some states ballots received prior to election day by mail or advance in-person voting are actually counted prior to election day or counted during the day - however it is a crime to publicly reveal these results prior to the close of polls)